# JDK points to wrong JRE

Tags: configuration, configuration-files, java

I had a portable JDK on a flashdrive and brought it over to my computer, however, it can not be used because the JDK points to the JRE on the flashdrive. How do I change this? Where are the java configuration files and what are they called?

Comment: which os do you use? Windows? then look in the registry under  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment

Answer (score 0):

Set the (system) environment variable to point to the flashdrive JDK location.  Also if you open a command prompt after doing this you will be able to execute `javac` and see some output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, try opening Control Panel and clicking on "Java".  You can edit a number of different settings from this panel.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way in windows creat batch file

set JDK_HOME= .\
set PATH=%PATH%;%JDK_HOME%\BIN